# Arrange SQL Server rows in a paired sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table in which a row has its matching pair. Checkpoint A has a matching pair checkpoint B. Every IN status has a matching OUT status. To match these exists a 'related_id' column with the id of the row it is related to.
Normally the table order can be as follows:

```
id | registration_no | checkpoint | related_id | status
 1      H2080              A            2          IN
 2      H2080              B            1          OUT
 3      H2081              A            8          IN
 4      H2070              A            6          IN
 5      H2087              A            7          IN          
 6      H2070              B            4          OUT          
 7      H2087              B            5          OUT
 8      H2081              B            3          OUT
```

but instead i would like it to be ordered in this way

```
id | registration_no | checkpoint | related_id | status
 1      H2080              A            2          IN
 2      H2080              B            1          OUT
 3      H2081              A            8          IN
 8      H2081              B            3          OUT
 4      H2070              A            6          IN          
 6      H2070              B            4          OUT          
 5      H2087              A            7          IN
 7      H2087              B            5          OUT
```

in which the leading checkpoint A is immediately followed by the matching checkpoint B by somehow using the related_id to tell which columns are paired together. So the rows will alternate between A->B then A->B and so on.

I hope i managed to explain the question.

Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Is this a simplified version, as you could simply `order by registration_no, checkpoint` to achieve the same result

Comment: order by registration_no, checkpoint lists the registration_no and the all the A checkpoints first then all the B checkpoints next. It doesn't list the A checkpoint immediately followed by its matching B checkpoint

Comment: @T.Mas but it does. At least in the example you posted.

Comment: I noticed. Im still trying to figure out what im doing wrong. Ill post an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    CASE checkpoint WHEN 'A' THEN id 
                    WHEN 'B' THEN related_id
    END,
    checkpoint ;
```

Comment: Yes, Yes Yes!!! This is it. Ooh thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Final result can be achieved in 2 ways.

```
CREATE TABLE testOrders
 (id INT,
  registration_no VARCHAR(64),
  [checkpoint] VARCHAR(8),
  related_id SMALLINT,
  [status] VARCHAR(8)
  ) 


INSERT INTO testOrders
 (id, registration_no, [checkpoint], related_id, [status])
 VALUES (1,      'H2080',              'A',            2,          'IN'),
        (2,      'H2080',              'B',            1,          'OUT'),
        (3,      'H2081',              'A',            8,          'IN'),
        (4,      'H2070',              'A',            6,          'IN'),
        (5,      'H2087',              'A',            7,          'IN')  ,       
        (6,      'H2070',              'B',            4,          'OUT') ,        
        (7,      'H2087',              'B',            5,          'OUT'),
        (8,      'H2081',              'B',            3,          'OUT')
```

2 ways to get the same result.

```
SELECT id, 
       registration_no, 
       [checkpoint], 
       related_id, 
       [status] 
FROM   testorders 
ORDER  BY registration_no, 
          [checkpoint]
```

[image]

```
SELECT id, 
       registration_no, 
       [checkpoint], 
       related_id, 
       [status] 
FROM   testorders 
ORDER  BY registration_no, 
          status
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer works well SqlWorldWide, but as i added more rows some with duplicate registation numbers the results get a bit distorted again but in general your response does my answer well

Comment: Ok. I did not realize that. At least if you have distinct id and related_id, can use the solution proposed by @ypercube .

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in a database is not ordered by default, and normally does not need to be. SQL operations are generally designed to deal with a "sack" of data, with no reference to the order.

As SqlWorldwide's answer provides, it is generally recommended that data be sorted at the query level (allowing any ordering appropriate for the output, or necessary for processing). Actually, it is frequently recommended (if your database is very busy) to provide the data unsorted to applications, and let the applications sort it.

It is possible to control the order your data is stored in the database. a *clustered index* does actually store the data in the order indicated by the index. However, sorting of results is **not** normally a good reason to set up a clustered index. Instead, it's a matter of providing the best results in your queries. When putting together a query plan, SQL looks at the data needed, the indexes available, and tries to figure out the fastest way to get you your data.